# Java RegEx: Split without losing token

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write regex that will split a string when there is whitespace followed by a negative sign followed by non whitespace.

Example:

```
"x -y".split(regex)
returns: String[]{"x","-y"};
```

Currently I'm using

```
(?<=\\s)-(?=\\S+)
```

for my regex; but this returns "x","y" and eats the negative sign. is there any way to not eat the negative sign?

Thanks!

Comment: `\s(?=\-\S)` perhaps? Find the whitespace, but make sure there is a negative sign followed by a non-whitespace character. ([demo](http://regexr.com?2tba2))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern:

```
\s(?=\-\S)
```

Example"

```
 String:  x -y z -x y z
Matches:   ^    ^
```

*Carets point to matches*

Demo:

**[Example Code](http://regexr.com?2tba2)**

Answer (score 3):

You may include the minus in the second group

```
\\s(?=-\\S+)
```

This gives you the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You are capturing the minus sign which is used to split. Therefore it is removed.

Two possible solutions:

a) add it to the second match because it has to be there otherwise the split wouldn't return this result
b) try `(\S*) (\S.*)` instead and do a match. This will return two results, "x" and "-y".

If the split function is such a simple one consider using the string split function. Its much faster than regex.

```
var result = "x -y".split(" -");
if (result.length == 2) result[1] = "-" + result[1];
```

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is a nice site to check your regular expressions. If you compare your regex with Howards you will see the difference. If you take mine and do a match, too.

Answer (score 0):

If there will always be a space between the values you want to split, consider using something like:

> "x -y".split(" -");

Just remember to put the `-` back in (if that is required).

Comment: It should only split if there's a negative sign. However you could split by `' -'`.

Comment: Thanks, I incorporated your suggestion into my answer.